# WPF window with blank space after system scale changed

Tags: c#, wpf

When I dock simple WPF window to right or left side when the system scaling set to 125% (or higher) and then return the system scale to original value 100% an ugly blank space appear at the bottom of the window as you can see here:

[image]

The WPF application is newly created with no change in code (pre-generated).

```
<Window x:Class="TestScale.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestScale"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The application is running on 4.7.1 .Net framework

Is this the default behavior? All other applications I've tried seems to behave correctly (they are downsized).
For me it seems that the Window has some problem with Measure/Arrange when the scale is changed and the window is docked to side.

Does anybody faced the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting default `Background="White"` ? also after resetting scale to 100% drag the window a lil ..Still Black region or gone ?

Comment: Setting window's background to white has no effect, the blank space is still black. When I drag the window (undock) or resize the window then the blank disappear immediately.

Comment: Yes that's rendering issue !

Comment: Probably you should open this issue at WPF page on github.

Comment: The ticket on ms forum is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/21199/blank-space-when-systems-scale-changed.html

Comment: You should also try updating your graphics Card drivers (must check) this may resolve this issue !